# Show related content when radio button is checked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

So, I have the following function in js that was supposed to show a related content when the value of the radio button is selected. However, it isn't working, the boxes won't show no matter what I do.

```
function select_movimento(value)
    {
        if(value==1)
            document.getElementById("linear").style.display="block";            
        else
            document.getElementById("linear").style.display="none"; 
        if(value==2)
            document.getElementById("circular").style.display="block";
        else
            document.getElementById("linear").style.display="none"; 
        if(value==3)
            document.getElementById("rotacional").style.display="block";
        else
            document.getElementById("linear").style.display="none";
        if(value==4)
            document.getElementById("mudanca_config_mao").style.display="block";
        else
            document.getElementById("linear").style.display="none";     
    }
```

These are the radios:

```
    <input name="tipomov" type="radio" value="1" onclick="select_movimento(this.value);">&nbsp;Linear</input>
    <input name="tipomov" type="radio" value="2" onclick="select_movimento(this.value);">&nbsp;Circular</input>
    <input name="tipomov" type="radio" value="3" onclick="select_movimento(this.value);">&nbsp;Rotacional</input>
    <input name="tipomov" type="radio" value="4" onclick="select_movimento(this.value);">&nbsp;Mudan&ccedil;a de Configura&ccedil;&atilde;o de M&atilde;o</input>
```

These are the contents that should appear:

```
<tr id="linear" height="30%" style="display:none;">
        <td>linear</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="circular" height="30%" style="display:none;">
        <td>circular</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rotacional" height="30%" style="display:none;">
        <td>rotacional</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="mudanca_config_mao" height="30%" style="display:none;">
        <td>mudanca de configuarcao</td>
    </tr>
```

It's probably a simple mistake, but I'm a beginner, so any help is welcome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **clean** and **plain** way:

a **relationship** between `<input>` and `<label>` that comes immediately afterwards. (You can put the input tags together in a `<form>`)

```
<form>
    <input id="r1" onclick="f(this.id)" type="radio" />
    <label>text</label>
    <input type="radio" ... />
    <label>text</label>
</form>
```

In the **function** f(this.id) we **pass** the **id** from the clicked `<input>` to access the `<label>`.
`<label>` is in JavaScript the **nextElementSibling** from `<input>`:

```
var element = document.getElementById("r1");
var text = element.nextElementSibling.innerHTML; // label text
```

HTML output:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

If the radio button is clicked, the **innerHTML** of `<div id="output"></div>`
will be the **innerHTML** of the label tag.

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerHTML = text; // label text
```

(Instead of `&nbsp;` use CSS margin-left)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLqL1p2r/3/)

Comment: thank you so much and sorry for the late response! Actually the problem was much simpler than that, I was calling another file in the beginnig of the document which contained the same function again, silly me right --' but yours was the best solution, I liked your way very much and it helped me see problem, thanks!

Comment: Always think about a simple, short and clean solution. If things become to "chaotically", delete everything and start new. :-) You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find wrong is that you missed to surround the row < tr> tags by a table < table> tag. I 've made it work in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2N25vTiXXkiNXdXDXdV8?p=info)

```
<table>
<tr id="linear" height="30%" style="display:none;">
    <td>linear</td>
</tr>
<tr id="circular" height="30%" style="display:none;">
    <td>circular</td>
</tr>
<tr id="rotacional" height="30%" style="display:none;">
    <td>rotacional</td>
</tr>
<tr id="mudanca_config_mao" height="30%" style="display:none;">
    <td>mudanca de configuarcao</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your logic of if and else statements.  All your else statements are turning off the "linear" text, instead of turning off the text corresponding to the value in the IF test.

I think what you meant to do is this:

```
    if(value==1)
        document.getElementById("linear").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("linear").style.display="none";
    if(value==2)
        document.getElementById("circular").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("circular").style.display = "none";
    if(value==3)
        document.getElementById("rotacional").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("rotacional").style.display = "none";
    if(value==4)
        document.getElementById("mudanca_config_mao").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("mudanca_config_mao").style.display = "none";
```